# Cobra init not working,: Command not found

Tags: linux, go, go-cobra

I am following [this guide](https://github.com/spf13/cobra/blob/master/cobra/README.md).

```
***@pop-os:~/go/src/foo$ cobra init --pkg-name foo
Command 'cobra' not found, but can be installed with:
sudo apt install cobra
```

My setup:

I have go 1.16 installed

```
$ go version 
go version go1.16.3 linux/amd64
```

my $GOPATH is set to ~/go

```
$ go env
...
GOPATH="/home/***/go"
```

What I have done:
I used the command

```
$ go get -u github.com/spf13/cobra/cobra
```

In my bin's dir I now find cobra

```
***@pop-os:~/go/bin$ ls
cobra
...
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: easiest thing to do is just create an alias in .zshrc or .bashrc
`alias cobra="~/go/bin/cobra"`

since it is already in the path

Comment: For anyone that's coming here with no issue in establishing their path environment variable or with pointing to the binary - simply with the binary installing. If you happened to have an issue with `cannot find package "github.com/hashicorp/hcl/hcl/printer`, then simply enable Go modules and try again via `env GO111MODULE=on go get github.com/spf13/cobra/cobra`.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use

```
go mod init <MODNAME>
~/go/bin/cobra-cli init
```

or keep reading to learn how to to make the `cobra-cli` command available on the command line.

This seems to be an issue of `$PATH` configuration. Because the `cobra-cli` command is not found, the path `~/go/bin` is not part of the `$PATH` variable. One can add the path like this:

```bash
export PATH="~/go/bin:$PATH"
```

and then use the `cobra-cli` command on the command-line. One can add that `export ...` command to `~/.bashrc` or a similar file to have the `PATH` configured properly on startup.

Comment: Thank you, explaining what is wrong is so helpful. The concept of $PATH is still not familiar to me. I will try to learn more about it.

Comment: Thank you, most times it's a path issue.

Answer (score 6):

The cobra command is now become cobra-cli.
see https://github.com/spf13/cobra#usage